# How to get NSTableView animation delegate events?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, osx-lion, nstableview

In the new 10.7 Lion `NSTableView`, you can animate insertion and removal of `NSTableCellViews` with sliding animations and the like. (I'm using `NSView`-based, not cell-based.)

Now, the problem is, I want to do something when those cell animation(s) are finished, except I'm not sure where to set the *delegate* for this.  Is there some standard way this should be done?  I've tried:

```
[[myTableView animator] setDelegate: self];
```

but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.  I'm assuming I should be implementing the `NSAnimationDelegate` protocol and looking for `animationDidEnd:` …

Is there some other way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting something like this before the lines of code that trigger table view animations (inserts, deletes, moves, etc.):

```
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{
    [self tableViewAnimationDidFinish];
}];

// inserts, deletes, etc.
```

Did you find any other solutions?

Comment: No, sadly I never did. We also abandoned this approach as it was overloading the NSTableView a bit too much ^_^ …